# Trigger: Trigger if someone INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger created that will log their username to ChangesLogtbl if they update, delete or insert in TblCurrentRec.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytriggerforinsert
 @username = username           <------------------itried to place something like this
ON TblCurrentRec
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO ChangesLogtbl
     values ('username', 'GETDATE')
END
GO
```

This works but I want this one to work on all tables within the schema. and also not to limit it on insert but to delete and update as well.
I tried using everything in and over the net and also copied and studied different sample but to no avail. I'm new to SQL and this is my very first time to create a trigger. Hope you guys can understand.

Thanks.

Comment: edit done. Sql-server tag added.

Comment: Triggers in SQL Server are **per table** - you **cannot** have "global" triggers for all tables

Comment: That's what I thought....in addition to the question, I have stated that in the picture I tried to user variable to insert the username thrown to the table to be inserted as well to the table for trigger. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot have any parameters for triggers - triggers just fire when something (an `INSERT` etc.) happens - no way for you to add parameters to a trigger. You need to rethink your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use of cursors and the `Information_Schema.Tables` view to create triggers on all tables of a database.

Answer (score 0):

TO cover other DML,

```
ON TblCurrentRec
AFTER INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE
```

Coming to schema level coverage, i doubt you can have a single trigger for all tables in schema.Triggers should be written to each table.

If it where `DDL` we can use `DATABASE TRIGGERS`